# Numerical Analysis using MATLAB. Find the condition number $\mu$

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra

Find the condition number $\mu = |A||A^{-1}|$ for the Hilbert Matrix $A$ using the uniform form.

$A =  \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
1 &\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} &\frac{1}{4} \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} &\frac{1}{4} &\frac{1}{5} \\
\frac{1}{3} &\frac{1}{4} &\frac{1}{5} &\frac{1}{6}\\
\frac{1}{4} &\frac{1}{5} &\frac{1}{6}&\frac{1}{7} \end{array} \right) $

So I have a couple of question:

1.What does *uniform form* mean?

2.What does $|A|$ stand for? Determinant?

3.Is all the problem about plugging the $A$ into the formula?

Does anyone know the algorithm of doing this in MATLAB?

Please help!
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this is a hand written question and either you or your instructor has made some minor mistakes. It's very likely that the original question should read:

> Find the condition number $\mu=\|A\|\|A^{-1}\|$ for the Hilbert Matrix $A$ using the **uniform norm**.

Here $\|X\|$ denotes the uniform norm of a matrix $X=(x_{ij})_{i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}}$. The uniform norm, a.k.a. *maximum row sum norm*, is the matrix norm induced by the vector norm $\|x\|_\infty$. It is defined by
$$
\|X\|=\max_{1\le i\le n}\,\sum_{j=1}^n|x_{ij}|.
$$
In matlab, $\|X\|$ can be calculated as $\mathtt{max(sum(abs(X),2))}$.

Comment: So the answer should look like: 
>>mu = (((A),))*(((inv(A)),)) ?

Comment: @vercammen Hmm, I can't read your comment because my browser is unable to render the unicode characters in it, but basically you should compute $\mu$ as $\mathtt{  max(sum(abs(X),2))\ast max(sum(abs(inv(X)),2))}$.

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote there:) Thank you!